# Can a check be destroyed or does it have to be returned to the person

Tags: united-states, debt-collection

I sent a check for a partial payment of a debt to a lawyer.   They now have requested I send them one check for the entire amount and once they receive that in-full check, they will destroy the partial check.    Can they destroy it or does it have to be returned to me?

Comment: I doubt they have a legal right to request payment in one check... aside from that, I think it is dangerous to send a second check while the first is still around. Depending on your trust level in them.

Comment: I would first ask why they want a single check for the full amount. Why isn't it enough if you send them a second check for the difference between what you were supposed to pay in total, and what you have already paid? Doing so would avoid the entire issue.

Comment: I think @MichaelKjörling's comment is the way to go. It would be silly and sound fraudulent if they do not accept this happy medium. If they provide a convincing reason for wanting a single check in the full amount then I would love to see an update to your question :-)

Comment: Just for information, here in Denmark, the check is so outdated and little used, that at the end of 2016, the banks will no longer accept checks from other banks. Electronic transfers is the way to go,

Comment: @Aganju: they can *request* what they like within reason ;-) Whether they can do you for non-payment on the basis you didn't jump through their hoops is another matter entirely.

Comment: This seems to be normal to require a single check.  Notable example: the USA Federal Communications Commission also requires payment in a single check (I just ran into that issue with them last week).

Answer (score 26):

My revised, bottom-line advice: offer to send a 2nd payment (preferably in the form of money order or cashier's check) for the difference you are agreeing to pay. I cannot imagine any reason why they would object to this - there is no fee to cash a check, there's less risk of error, and less work involved. Alternatively, offer to send a new check only once the other has been returned. Don't issue one more full-amount check while the other is still outstanding.

There is a good reason not to accept partial payment by them, which is that accepting a partial payment of a debt comes with a varieties of strings attached depending on the nature of the debt (such as with evictions, court processes may need to be restarted, etc). They likely want to avoid such a situation - but this does not provide any support for why they can't just take a second payment and then cash it all at once as a single, full settlement of the debt.

In a perfect world, you could skip all the non-sense by simply having your bank put a stop-payment on the old check before sending a new one. Unfortunately, this might not work with 100% accuracy - but in your case if the "partial payment" is a significant amount of money to you, I'd go ahead and spend the $20-40 to put in the order now as an extra safety on them not doing what they claim, if for some incredibly stupid reason you can't handle this with a 2nd payment instead of one single full one.

It turns out banks have lots of surprising and stupid rules, like stop payments on a check expiring in 6 months (and they may even cash stale checks over a year old), no guarantee of a stop being successful, etc. The real rule is: they might cash the check unless you close the account. Sigh - this is one of many reasons I never, ever use checks.

I am not aware of any law that requires a check to be physically returned if requested, or proof or destruction provided, or anything like that. It's a large part of the reason why we have the ability to stop payment on a check, and so void it through the bank without having any physical access to the check - but this process is spotty and imperfect, and cannot be relied upon.

You can request them to do whatever you like, like void it and send it back, or destroy it, and they can just refuse - or say they'll do it and then just not do it, and you have no real useful recourse.

The main goal should be to avoid losing money if someone "accidentally" (or intentionally) cashes both checks. So you can ask, or demand (refuse to pay until they return the check), etc - and they can respond more or less any way they want.

As a final piece of future advice, consider no longer using checks for purposes like this. Switch to using something like a cashier's check or money order offered by your bank, which (by their very nature) takes the money out of your account immediately, severs all ongoing connection to your bank account, and is effectively like cash with the added benefit of a paper trail. Keep the stub and and receipt from the cashier's check/money order, in case it is lost or they claim they didn't get the money.

Comment: I disagree. A 'stop payment' usually comes with a significant fee (25 $ or so), and it might still get paid if they deposit it, and _you_ spend the next six month discussing with the bank to get it back.

Comment: @Aganju I thought you were surely wrong about banks still cashing a stopped check...but apparently this is not impossible, and I'm again reminded why I never ever use checks anymore. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: +1 for "never, ever use checks." They are the most unsafe (in terms of risks from both malice and from mistakes) form of payment. If you **must** send paper payment by mail, use a cashier's check or money order.

Comment: Probably add the caveat that it's a business (a law firm at that), and therefore unlikely to maliciously cash your "cancelled" check. It's much more likely they wanted the partial payment check as some sort of hold, and will actually destroy (shred) the check once full payment is received.

Comment: @SnakeDoc My read is that it's a debt collection firm (which may also be a law practice), and there is a long history of being willing to say pretty much anything to collect money - valid debt or no, sometimes even claiming to settle a debt for less (and then not actually settling the debt). They also tend to refuse to put anything in writing, as a general operating procedure. Cashing both could be anywhere from malicious to accidental, and if that happens there is no easy recourse.

Comment: @BrianDHall Never send a debt collection agency any money until you have in writing before-hand what the payment is for and what it means for the rest of your debt. In fact, no action should be taken with a debt collection agency unless you have writing first.

Comment: I cannot imagine that there is any significant advantage for the lawyer to cash one check instead of two.  Depositing two checks is marginally more work than depositing one check.  And depositing one check while destroying another is certainly more work than depositing two checks.  I can understand why they want payment in full, but this whole business about "we want it all in one check" seems suspicious to me.  I would send a second check to cover the remaining balance, not a new check covering the total payment.

Comment: @R.. Why are cashier's checks safer?

Comment: @SnakeDoc: I would replace that with just "never send a debt collection agency any money", full stop. They've always done something sufficiently illegal that you can get out of paying them anything by threatening to escalate.

Comment: @whrrgarbl: With regards to the situation in the question, it's because if you ask the bank to stop payment on it and refund you the money you paid, the money is back in your hands. If the bank later honors it, it's the bank who lost money, not you. But more importantly in general, there's no overdraft risk. The money is withdrawn from your account at the moment the cashier's check is issued, not weeks or months later when the recipient cashes it.

Comment: @R.. That makes sense, thanks! Most of what I'd read was only about relative safety for the person trying to receive the money, not send it.

Comment: @R.. I tend to agree, however in some cases, you will not want it marked down as "settled" on your record, and they've not done anything blatantly illegal... so you end up having to pay off your rightfully owed debt. Just get everything in writing, always.

Comment: @SnakeDoc: I've had cases where the party they were collecting for actually owed me money for other reasons (I stopped paying my phone bill several months before moving because the phone company refused to fix over-charges) and replied to their letters with a request to enlist their services to collect from the phone company. They shut up after that. :-)

Comment: @R.. Just because the collection calls and letters stop, doesn't mean they aren't still reporting delinquency. I trust you resolved your case - just wanted to mention that for others.

Comment: From the partial payment perspective, would one possible risk to the recipient of two cheques be that you only have some of the funds, so one clears while the other doesn't - giving a partial payment after all. With a single cheque, it's all or nothing - so it may bounce, but can never produce a partial.

Comment: It is not true that there is no cost for cashing a check. Many businesses have to pay small, per-check fees.

Comment: Cashier's checks often cost money, and if the cashier's check is lost in the post it may be expensive or impossible to stop.

Answer (score 7):

What would you do if you had the check?  Probably destroy it.  The goal is to render it uncashable.  One way to do such is to have it shredded.

If you are uncomfortable leaving them to destroy it, then swing by and pick it up.  Alternatively offer to send them a self addressed and stamped envelope.  I am sure they will accommodate if you ask nicely.

Comment: If you're going to physically go to their office anyways, you might as well deliver the new check in person but demand to be handed the old check in exchange.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the trust level you have in them handling it correctly.

If they never deposit it, it doesn't matter what happens to the check, they could frame it and hang it on the wall. The risk is that someone someday deposits it (incorrectly double-charging you), and you need to do what think is appropriate to avoid this risk. If your trust in them is too small, only sending it back to you makes sure that you physically control the check.

Comment: And even physically sending it back is no guarantee that they haven't electronically presented it.

Answer (score -1):

There is no law requiring someone to return a refused check.

You need to clarify whether this payment is to establish a retainer, or to pay for services rendered. Either way you should stop payment on the check and send them a certified letter explaining that you are stopping payment on the check because they refused it.

If the payment is to establish a retainer, then the issue is simple: the lawyer requires $10,000 as a retainer before you can engage them and until then you have no relationship with them. If that is the amount they want, then less than that is not accepted.

If the payment is for services rendered already and you owe them money, then it is a completely different situation. Refusing partial payment means they are getting ready to sue you. In a collection suit, the larger the amount is, the better. Normally, someone owed money will only refuse a partial payment if they anticipate having to sue the debtor and they want to maximize their leverage in case of a court judgement in their favor. A creditor has the right to refuse a partial payment.